# Salesforce Apex - POSTing multipart/form-data Content-Type

Tags: apex, callout

I am following through Dan's interesting blog (http://www.fishofprey.com/2017/04/steps-required-to-support-posting.html) which has proved to make the impossible possible on salesforce apex for lot Salesforce developer for POSTing multipart/form-data Content-Type (No Native Salesforce support for this at the moment).

I have tested the REST Endpoint using curl/Postman and it works without any issues. But when try from salesforce's HTTP callout, service responds with the below error.

502 - Kong Error: An invalid response was received from the upstream server.

It will immensely be appreciable if someone can correct me and point me in the right direction. Below is the Code that I am sharing with you.

```
public static void fileUploadCallout(string idStr) 
{
 string Endpoint = 'https:********';
 string xAPIKey = '***********';
 string verticalId = '*******';
 string callbackURL = '**************';

 List<contentversion> cvList = new List<contentversion>();
 cvList = [select id, title, ContentDocumentId, FileExtension, versionData, CMS_SEI_AV_Scan_Status__c, CMS_SEI_Scan_Status_Log__c from contentversion where Id = :idStr limit 1];
 System.debug('Callout Log 1:' + cvList);
 if(!cvList.isEmpty())     
 {
  //form fileName with cv ID
  string fileName = cvList[0].Id;
  if(cvList[0].FileExtension!=null && cvList[0].FileExtension!='')
  {
   fileName = fileName + '.' + cvList[0].FileExtension;  
  }         
  System.debug('Callout Log 2:' + fileName);

  //callout ePOR service
  string contentType = EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart.GetContentType();

  //  Compose the form
  string form64 = '';

  form64 += EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart.WriteBoundary();
  //form64 += EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart.WriteBodyParameter('labelId', EncodingUtil.urlEncode(labelId, 'UTF-8'));
  //form64 += EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart.WriteBoundary();
  form64 += EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart.WriteBodyParameter('name', EncodingUtil.urlEncode(fileName, 'UTF-8'));
  form64 += EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart.WriteBoundary();
  form64 += EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart.WriteBodyParameter('data', EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cvList[0].versionData));
  form64 += EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart.WriteBoundary(EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart.EndingType.CrLf);

  blob formBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(form64);
  string contentLength = string.valueOf(formBlob.size());

  System.debug('Callout Log 3:' + formBlob.size());

  if(formBlob.size()>12000000)
  {
   //this a "public class CustomException extends Exception{}"
   throw new CustomException('File size limit is 12 MBytes');
  }
  else
  {
     HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
     req.setMethod('POST');
     req.setEndpoint(Endpoint);
     req.setBodyAsBlob(formBlob);
     req.setHeader('apiKey', xAPIKey);
     req.setHeader('vertid', verticalId);
     req.setHeader('callback', callbackURL);
     req.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
     req.setHeader('Content-Length', contentLength);
     req.setHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
     req.setTimeout(120000);
     Http http =new Http();
     HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
     System.debug('Callout Log 4:' + res.getStatusCode());
     System.debug('Callout Log 5:' + String.valueof(res.getbody()));

     string responseStatusCode = String.valueof(res.getStatusCode()); 
     string responseBody = String.valueof(res.getbody()); 

  }
```

http://www.fishofprey.com/2017/04/steps-required-to-support-posting.html

Comment: Do you have the corresponding cURL or Postman request for comparison? Feel free to obscure the apiKey etc...

Comment: What version of `EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart` are you using? It needs to be the [modified version that applies the correct CRLF fix](https://github.com/muenzpraeger/salesforce-einstein-vision-apex/blob/master/src/classes/EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart.cls). Note the way it also includes the `filename` - `public static string WriteBlobBodyParameter(string key, string file64, string fileName)`

Comment: This is the version of EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart that I am using: https://github.com/muenzpraeger/salesforce-einstein-vision-apex/blob/master/src/classes/EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart.cls

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than using `EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart.WriteBodyParameter` to append the blob data you need to use `EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart.WriteBlobBodyParameter`.

The latter performs extra steps to handle the encoding of the last bytes before the Boundary is added. Note that it will also write it's own boundary.

---

Final solution provided by @user2662369

```
@future(callout=true)
public static void fileUploadCallout(string idStr) 
{
 string Endpoint = 'https:********';
 string xAPIKey = '***********';
 string verticalId = '*******';
 string callbackURL = '**************';

 List<contentversion> cvList = new List<contentversion>();
 cvList = [select id, title, ContentDocumentId, FileExtension, versionData from contentversion where Id = :idStr limit 1];
 System.debug('Callout Log 1:' + cvList);
 if(!cvList.isEmpty())     
 {
  //form fileName with cv ID
  string fileName = cvList[0].Id;
  if(cvList[0].FileExtension!=null && cvList[0].FileExtension!='')
  {
   fileName = fileName + '.' + cvList[0].FileExtension;  
  }         
  System.debug('Callout Log 2:' + fileName);

  //callout ePOR service
  string contentType = EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart.GetContentType();

  //  Compose the form
  string form64 = '';
  //******This was the boundary I was missing****
  form64 += EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart.WriteBoundary();
  form64 += EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart.WriteBlobBodyParameter('file', EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cvList[0].versionData), fileName);

  blob formBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(form64);
  string contentLength = string.valueOf(formBlob.size());

  System.debug('Callout Log 3:' + formBlob.size());

  if(formBlob.size()>12000000)
  {
   //this a "public class CustomException extends Exception{}"
   throw new CustomException('File size limit is 12 MBytes');
  }
  else
  {
     HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
     req.setMethod('POST');
     req.setEndpoint(Endpoint);
     req.setBodyAsBlob(formBlob);
     req.setHeader('apiKey', xAPIKey);
     req.setHeader('vertid', verticalId);
     req.setHeader('callback', callbackURL);
     req.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
     req.setHeader('Content-Length', contentLength);
     req.setHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
     req.setTimeout(120000);
     Http http =new Http();
     HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
     System.debug('Callout Log 4:' + res.getStatusCode());
     System.debug('Callout Log 5:' + String.valueof(res.getbody()));

     string responseStatusCode = String.valueof(res.getStatusCode()); 
     string responseBody = String.valueof(res.getbody()); 

  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Sure, will try that now.

Comment: curl -vk -X POST -F "file=@C:/Users/mrasheed/Desktop/Test.png" https://********.***.***/***/v2/objects/ -H "APIkey: ******************************" -H "verticalId: ************" -H "callbackurl: https://*********************************"

Comment: As per your suggestion, I changed it to EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart.WriteBlobBodyParameter and the Service is still returning "502 - Kong Error: An invalid response was received from the upstream server." Thanks for the help.

Comment: string contentType = EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart.GetContentType();

  string form64 = '';
  form64 += EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart.WriteBlobBodyParameter('file', EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cvList[0].versionData), fileName);
 
  blob formBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(form64);
  string contentLength = string.valueOf(formBlob.size());

Comment: Hi Dan, I just created RequestBin version of the callout and I received Status Code:200| Response Body: ok| Here is request bin: https://requestb.in/1kwg49t1?inspect

Comment: Here is the contentversion file that got uploaded to requestbin: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Nfrnj7U4UsUlhZM2w2UWNhTjg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I was missing the boundary before the line EinsteinVision_HttpBodyPart.WriteBlobBodyParameter. Thank you so much, Dan! I can't express this joy in words!!!!! Let me know if I need to do anything more than marking this answer!!!!!

Comment: @user2662369 Great news! I'm glad that I was able to help you in the right direction. Can you do a suggested edit on the answer with the code that you ended up using? Or email it to me and I'll merge it in. The goal is to help the next developer who needs to try something like this get it working quicker.

Comment: Sure, I will do that!

Comment: I have added the working code to the answer, Thanks Again Dan!

Comment: @DanielBallinger `writeBlobBodyParameter` when we try to iterate over list of blob objects and then run this method, it only sends the first file. Rest all files it ignores. Any suggestions.

Comment: @NagendraSingh I'd suggest asking a new question and adding the details of what you have tried and how it is failing. It will be easier to handle in a dedicated question. Feel free to link it back to this question.

Comment: @DanielBallinger I have posted a question : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/299234/multipart-formdata-from-fails-to-pass-multiple-jpg-files

Comment: @DanielBallinger I have posted question with examples and hosted a rest endpoint for you to try. Please have look, I am stuck here. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/299234/multipart-form-data-uploads-only-the-first-file-when-using-httpformbuilder-exam

Anonymous apex example has also been given.