# Sending 100KB attachment via HTTPRequest throws System.UnexpectedException

Tags: rest-api, attachment, httprequest, blob

I'm trying to upload an attachment from SF to a third party server using REST API,

First, my third party does not support `base64` content-transfer so I cannot send from SF a `base64` attachment.

Second - once the attachment is larger than 100KB, I get this exception (works well with files smaller than 100KB)
:

> System.UnexpectedException: Script-thrown exception

This is my code - I wrote a very simple code for testing, and I am testing with pdf / docx files:

```
private static HttpResponse sendAttachment(Attachment caseAtt, String endpoint){

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/xml');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data'); //tried with 'application/pdf' (for pdf file)
    req.setHeader('content-length', String.valueOf(caseAtt.body.size()));
    req.setHeader('accept-encoding', 'gzip, deflate, br');
    req.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
    req.setTimeout(120000);
    req.setEndpoint(endpoint);

    req.setBodyasBlob(caseAtt.body);

    try{
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
        return res;
    }catch(CalloutException ex){
        system.debug('CalloutException: '+ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        system.debug('Exception: '+ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    }}
```

**QUESTION**

1. Is there a limitation in SF for sending files larger than 100KB via `HttpRequest` (I found [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008mLMIAY) article, but it is very old so I am not sure about it)?
2. Is there a different approach for sending large files to a third party?

Posts I tried their solution but did not work:

- https://www.topcoder.com/blog/reblog-post-multipartform-data-with-httprequest-by-enreeco/
- http://www.fishofprey.com/2017/04/steps-required-to-support-posting.html
- [Send Blob file via Apex Rest Callout](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180311/send-blob-file-via-apex-rest-callout)

Comment: I can not see any header for authrization

Comment: Its defined as a named credential in salesforce: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm

Comment: O...got it...endpoint was not visible ...so I thought ..